# Combining Multiple Falcor Data Sources into Single Model

Tags: falcor

**Modified the question to explain better:**

I have two Falcor models from two different HttpDataSource, like below:

First model (User model):

```
const user_model = new falcor.Model(
{
  source: new HttpDataSource('http://localhost:3000/api/userManagement')
});
user_model.get(['user', 'list'])
```

OUTPUT1:

```
{
    "jsonGraph": {
        "user": {
            "list": {
                "$type": "atom",
                "value": {
                    "users": [...]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second model (Role model):

```
const role_model = new falcor.Model(
{
  source: new HttpDataSource('http://localhost:3000/api/roleManagement')
});

role_model.get(['role', 'list'])
```

OUTPUT2:

```
{
    "jsonGraph": {
        "role": {
            "list": {
                "$type": "atom",
                "value": {
                    "roles": [...]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to combine all these Falcor models into a single model?

The purpose is, if I try to do user_model.get(['user', 'list']) more than once it would get the data from Falcor-Model-Cache (after the first fetch from DB).

But if I try to do role_model.get(['user', 'list']), then I have to hit the DB again to get the data (inorder to store the same User list in role_model cache).

So instead if there is a way like below:

```
all_model = user_model + role_model
```

then I can do all_model.get(['user', 'list']) (or) all_model.get(['role', 'list']). So basically I would have only one combined Falcor-Model-Cache at the browser end.

Hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: what does the graphJSON look like for each source?  Would you want to merge keySets across each (probably harder), or are they disjoint from one another (probably easier)?

Answer (score 0):

You must use forkJoin

```
forkJoin(model1.source,model2.source).subscribe(res=>{
    //in res[0] you have the response of model1.source
    //in res[1] you have the response of model2.source
    let data={...res[0],...res[1]}
    //in data you have all the properties
}
```

Comment: I believe what you said would be just combining the result of all falcor model calls (i.e.) just the data. But the combined Falcor Data source should be used for subsequent data calls, where the data if already present in the Falcor Model cache would be served from there & not from an Api call.